# Why do sites sometimes show a box containing the site stats on the righthand side, but sometimes don't?

Tags: support

I'm always interested to check, but usually it doesn't appear.

Why is that? It seems to have no rhyme or reason.

Comment: Are we talking about the difference between the front-page and the questions-page?

Comment: Nope, front page only. Some sites seem to show the stats box on their homepage sometimes, while others don't at other times.  It all seems to not abide by any sort of logic.

Comment: Examples and screenshots please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are talking about [beta Stack Exchange sites](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=beta), such as 
[Project Management beta](https://pm.stackexchange.com/)

These are the only sites that show the statistics on the home page. They are an indication of how the site is faring.

Comment: So sites only show their stats on the homepage when they're still in beta phase?

Comment: @adlwalrus - yes

Comment: That's kind of lame, I think.